# Regex to Scrape Names

Tags: regex

I have being trying to pull Names from a list of data

The Data Looks like this

```
Seller: Jim Vaughan 
Clicks ordered: 100 
Clicks received: 115 
Optin: 43.91% 
Sales: 2 
Tier1: 80% 
I'm happy with the results, the solo paid for itself will be back for more!
```

I want to get just the name from it

I tried this

```
[a-zA-z]+[\b]{1}[a-zA-z]+[\b]{1}[a-zA-z]+
```

But that didn't worked. May some body please help me figure out how to get just the names from it?

Comment: Will the name always be in that format (i.e. Uppercase first letter for fn & ln? If so Avinash's answer would do the trick.

Comment: Don't limit the name like that. `Jörgeé Dougan-Klaußen` or `Madonna` are legally valid names. See http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: One problem is probably in `[a-zA-z]`, which should have been `[a-zA-Z`] (the 'Z' needs to be uppercase after the 'A').

Comment: @OnlineCop But the OP isn't mentioned that the names must be after the `Seller:` field.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Since the OP stated "`The Data Looks like this`", I assume that it literally has that structure/format, and with that concrete format, I can give a concrete regex. If the format is actually different, the OP can update the question with a more accurate one, and we can help at that point.

Comment: If your data will always be in this format, abandon regex and just split each line into key value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below regex would match exactly the names which is just after `SELLER:` or `Seller:` or `Seller Name:`

```
(?<=Seller:\s|SELLER:\s|Seller Name:\s).*?\b[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dZ0zC0/2)

Comment: that does the trick but it also match data like if somebody write Clicks Received then it will match that too but is getting close

Comment: @Manny does the names must be after `Seller:`?

Comment: What would be the pattern to find the names? Any clues does it would be at the last of a line?

Comment: Yes they have Seller: most of the time but sometimes they write like SELLER: or Seller Name:

Comment: yes but that grabs all after it so I made a change and it looks like it works (?<=Seller:\s|SELLER:\s|Seller Name:\s|SELLER NAME:\s)[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+ thans a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should never assume that names follow a [specific pattern](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

In your example, search for `Seller:` and capture everything after that:

```
^(?<=Seller: )(.*)$
               \1     (replacement)
```

If your language doesn't support look-behinds (like Javascript), capture the `Seller:` portion as well and then just reference the `\2` element:

```
(Seller: )(.*)$
   \1      \2          (replacement)
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/wZ1pE3/1)

Answer (score -1):

I think this may do it

```
[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+$
```

This will match a string ending with the pattern of one upper-case letter, followed by one or more lower-case letters, followed by a space, and then that pattern repeated again for the second name.

Comment: Using `{1}` is redundant: `[A-Z]` will already match a single uppercase letter.

Comment: I edited this post accordingly and believe it now offers a viable, clean solution.

Comment: Answers on SO are much more useful if you explain how they help, rather than just posting code.

Comment: Look at that. I think I learn something new every time I visit this site. Etiquette, efficiency, efficacy, robustness and the like. See now that I added an explanation, though I trust this asker understands the ins and outs of regular expressions well enough to follow what I posted. Perhaps other viewers won't, though.